# How do I limit dotCover to analyse only one set of assemblies in a multi-targeted build?

Tags: .net, .net-core, dotcover

I have multitargeted dotnet project, and I'm trying to use dotCover inside Visual Studio to improve my test coverage.

Unfortunately, my classes are currently built for both core and framework

```
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>
```

but my MSTest assemblies are only built for dotnet core

```
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

This means that when I build and run the unit tests for dotCover, it detects every assembly twice, one with code coverage (netstandard2.0), and one with 0% code coverage (net461).

The result is that opening the "Hot Spots" view highlights classes as complex and 0% tested, even though they are actually 100% tested.

I would like to add a "Coverage Filter" to dotCover to get it to ignore the second build target, but I cannot come up with a valid filter in the UI.  I can only see a way to filter by assembly (and class and method name) or attribute.

Can anyone suggest a way to get dotCover to ignore my net461 "secondary" build assemblies when it's trying to calculate coverage?

For reference : I'm using dotnet core sdk 2.2, dotCover 2019.3.2 (as part of Resharper) and Visual Studio 2019.  The tests are using MSTest

Comment: The results should be presented in a separate trees, per [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/whatsnew/#multiple-target-frameworks)

Comment: They are shown in different trees, but the “Hot Spots” view definitely is not and does not seem to have filtering.